# List <string> does not contain definition for 'Length' and no accessible extension method 'Length'

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .csv file containing a table name plus a data. I need to construct it. Here's my code The problem is the List  does not contain definition for `'Length'`

```
 class Program
{
    public static string fileName = @".\file.csv";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> lines = fileReader(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Insert INTO " + lines[0].Trim(',') + " (" + lines[1] + ")");
        Console.WriteLine("VALUES");
        var reciept_num = new List<string>();
        var reciept_date = new List<string>();
        var reciept_total = new List<string>();
        var reciept_payment = new List<string>();
        var reciept_change = new List<string>();
        var item_sold = new List<string>();
        var item_price = new List<string>();
        var item_quantity = new List<string>();
        var item_total = new List<string>();
```

Here's the error. the '`Length'` Please help me with this.

```
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
            

            {
                string[] col = lines[i].Split(',');

            reciept_num.Add(col[0]);
            reciept_date.Add(col[1]);
            reciept_total.Add(col[2]);
            reciept_payment.Add(col[3]);
            reciept_change.Add(col[4]);
            item_sold.Add(col[5]);
            item_price.Add(col[6]);
            item_quantity.Add(col[7]);
            item_total.Add(col[8]);
        }

      

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is my file reader to my csv file. I think this code of reading a csv file is fine.

```
    public static List<string> fileReader(string filePath)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string line = "";

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Message: Please close the file and try again");
        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=net-6.0

Comment: Look at the documentation for the `IList` interface. It *doesn't* contain a `Length` property. It does, however, contain a `Count` property.

Comment: Closing as a typo

Comment: @DanielMann u r right.

Comment: got it @DanielMann

Comment: Rather than 9 (nine!) parallel lists you might want to investigate the use of *classes*.  Likewise there are much better, faster and easier CSV processing means such as CSVHelper.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp How's that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here's what Daniel Mann tryin to say.

> for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count; i++)

Using a `Count` property. Instead of `Length` property.